# declare variable type for destructured variables in one statement

Tags: rust, types

In rust, I would like to declare the variable types for variables created in a "destructuring" statement. Is this possible? Is there a not-yet-approved rust RFC?

For example, this rust code destructures a returned tuple ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0cce8e8d3c3c2a3e41727258983facea))

```rust
fn return_stuff() -> (i32, u32) {
    (-1 as i32, 1 as u32)
}

fn main() {
    let (a, b) = return_stuff();
}
```

However, I ***cannot declare the types for `a` and `b` within one statement***:

```rust
fn return_stuff() -> (i32, u32) {
    (-1 as i32, 1 as u32)
}

fn main() {
    let (a: i32, b: u32) = return_stuff();
}
```

The compiler fails with error

```
error: expected one of `)`, `,`, `@`, or `|`, found `:`
```

I know I can declare `a` and `b` types in multiple statements ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b67f8f24471c68368ff9449eabf8bda)):

```
fn return_stuff() -> (i32, u32) {
    (-1 as i32, 1 as u32)
}

fn main() {
    let a: i32;
    let b: u32;
    (a, b) = return_stuff();
}
```

I would like to declare `a` and `b` types in one statement. `let (a: i32, b: u32) = ...`
Is this possible?
Is there a rust RFC in-progress to allow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the type of the tuple, not the types of its members. The type of `(-1i32, 1u32)` is `(i32, u32)`.

```
fn return_stuff() -> (i32, u32) {
    (-1, 1) // the type casts are unnecessary
}

fn main() {
    let (a, b): (i32, u32) = return_stuff();
}
```

Comment: I should mention that in most cases the type annotations are wholly unnecessary, but I presume you have a case that actually necessitates them.