# annotate type for "for loop" variables

Tags: rust, typing

In rust, I would like to annotate the variable types for variables created in a *for loop* statement.

##### example code

For example, in this rust *for loop* variable `i` is a `Iter<i32>` ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=64cbf5e3a3b8d1e13540521b7bccbfc8))

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec::<i32> = vec![-1, 22, -333];
    for i in my_vec.iter() {
        eprintln!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

---

However, I ***cannot annotate the type for `i` within the for loop statement or before it***:

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec::<i32> = vec![-1, 22, -333];
    let mut i: Iter<i32>;
    for i in my_vec.iter() {
        eprintln!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

The compiler warns

```
warning: unused variable: `i`
```

Other syntax variations fail to compile, e.g.:

```rust
    for i: Iter<i32> in my_vec.iter() {
```

---

I would like to annotate `i` type in one *for loop* statement.
Is this possible?
Is there a rust RFC in-progress to allow this?

##### Why explicitly annotate `i`?

Often the original type is declared or annotated in some far away source code, like maybe in a different crate.

1. Sometimes, my IDE isn't able to deduce the type despite the code being compileable.
2. Code reviewing humans are unable to deduce the expected type (they are not viewing the code with the help of Intellisense popups).

Being explicit about the type might be helpful.

##### Related question

This question is similar but not the same as [a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73227599/declare-variable-type-for-destructured-variables-in-one-statement).

Comment: If you are using iterators to loop like that, `i` will always be the same type of the iterator's `Item`. You can use a count-controlled loop and specify the type of the counter, but then you lose the iterator features.

Comment: The `i32` in `Vec::<i32>` is the type - is there a particular reason you're looking to re-specify it? There is probably a better way to get at what you're really trying to do.

Comment: "_is the type - is there a particular reason you're looking to re-specify it_", yes. Often the original type is declared in some far away source code, like maybe in a different crate. My IDE isn't able to deduce the type, so I can't get IDE help. Also, code reviewing humans are unable to deduce the expected type.  So being explicit about the type is helpful. I added _Why_ to the question.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon So you don't want to **declare** it, but you want to **annotate** it. That's a whole different topic. I guess you can understand the word *declare* that way, but I read it more as *overwrite*. This makes this discussion much clearer now :D

Comment: "_you don't want to declare it, but you want to annotate it_". Yes, that's an important distinction.  I will update the question.

Comment: In this case take this link:
https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/354#issuecomment-257967827
And no, the answer is this does not exist in Rust currently. People want it, but they didn't want it enough that it happened. Maybe it happens some day.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon updated my answer to reflect your actual question